# Error while outputting template engine maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, html, django

The problem is that I get an error when I try to display a block on a page, I don't really know what to do, since I'm working with a template engine for the first time.
this is code of views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods
context_object_name = 'goods'

def sale(request):
    return render(request, 'articles/sale.html')
```

this is code of index.html

```html
{% include "article/sale.html" %}
{% block sale %}

{% endblock %}
```

this is code of sale.html

```html
{% extends "Homepage/index.html" %}

{% block sale %}

<td class ="sale">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1280px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png">

        <h1 class="description">ОписаниеОписаниеОписаниеОписание</h1>

  <a class="buy" href="#openModal" >
    <span >Купить</span></a>
  <h1 class="price">цена</h1>
  </td>


{% endblock %}
```

This is building a template
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

in the end it gives an error    `maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`
вот TraceBack
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: your `index.html` includes the `sale.html` which will then `extend` the `index.html`, you thus have two items that include each other, and hence will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `index.html` template *includes* the `sales.html` template, and the `sales.html` template extends the `index.html` template. As a result if you render `index.html` or `sale.html`, it will get stuck in an infinite loop.

You can *remove* the <s>`{% include 'article/sales.html' %}`</s> part of the `index.html` page. The fact that you defined a block that can be filled in by the `sales.html` template is sufficient.

Comment: thanks a lot, but now the block is not displayed

Comment: @Licrencie: the `template_name` should be `template_name = 'article/sales.html'`

Comment: Where to add it ?, in the indexview class

Comment: @Licrencie: yes.

Comment: And there is no other option, do I understand correctly?

Comment: I think that you misunderstand how the Django webserver works: the urls determine which view is triggered. A view can render zero, one or more templates to make it easier to pass content, but the view renders the template, not the opposite way: it is not because your request has the same name as a template that it will render all the views that render that template to generate a response.